# What does "2>&1" do when posted BEFORE 1>x?

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, pipe

I know what this command does:

```
command 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

But what, if anything, does the following do?

```
command 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

I still see standard error output with the second command, so it doesn't do what I expected it to do at least...

This is reproduced on both Windows/cmd.exe and Linux/Bash (I was about to ask this question on *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* instead of Super User, but I noticed that it can be reproduced on Windows cmd.exe too, so I guess it fits better on Super User than Unix & Linux then?)

Comment: I describe `2>&1` as "redirected fd2 to _whatever fd1 is currently using_" -- subsequently redirecting fd1 does not affect what fd2 is using.

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 26):

A further example might be helpful: let's redirect fd1 to a file, redirect fd2 to fd1, then redirect fd1 to a different file:

```bsh
$ ( echo "this is stdout"; echo "this is stderr" >&2 ) 1>foo 2>&1 1>bar
$ cat foo
this is stderr
$ cat bar
this is stdout
```

We can see that `2>&1` sends stderr to the "foo" file that stdout was redirected to, but when we redirect stdout to "bar" we don't alter stderr's destination.

Similarly, `2>&1 1>/dev/null` redirects stderr to whatever stdout is pointing to (see `/proc/$$/fd`), and when stdout is discarded, stderr is not altered (still visible).

This is the technique used to capture a command's error output, ignoring the regular output:

```bsh
error_output=$( some_command  2>&1 1>/dev/null )
```

Answer (score 12):

From `man bash`:

"Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the command

```
ls > dirlist 2>&1
```

directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist, while the command

```
ls 2>&1 > dirlist
```

directs  only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was duplicated from the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist."

Answer (score 7):

It is a problem with the ordering of operations. You expect `2>&1` to redirect to `1`, but instead it is redirecting to the current *value* of `1` instead. It feels a little like a "race condition" but isn't really, you expect both operations to happen at the same time, but they are evaluated one after the other and the value at that specific moment is what matters, not the end value.

By default `1` is pointing at your default console output `stdout` so doing `2>&1` at that point is redirecting `stderr` to your standard console output `stdout`.

By doing  `2>&1` *after* redirecting `1` to another file you are redirecting it to the *new* file pointer that `1` points to. (`/dev/null`)

Essentially the redirection operator *copies* the pointer from where you are redirecting to rather than pointing to the other descriptor. As such the order of redirections is important.

Comment: I too would not call this a race condition but I don't know that i would have a better word to describe what Mokubai is describing.  Your name makes me hungry for Hawaiian breakfast.. "I would like the Mokubai Locobai please! with extra gravy!..

Comment: @DanielB hopefully clarified.

Comment: [Race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) happen when two (or more) _simultaneous_ threads or processes (or whatever) try to do things at the same time, without synchronization, so that the result depends on external factors enough to be essentially random. This is absolutely nothing like that: the processing of redirections is quite well defined, and happens exactly in order, left to right.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I would call it this: Misinterpreting imperative syntax (an *instruction* telling the shell to perform an operation) as declarative syntax (a *configuration* under which the shell should run a command). Redirection is the former, but it's easy to misread it as the latter.

Comment: @Kevin, I am a 30+ year c/c++ developer and my statement was really sort of rhetorical.  Thank you though.  Perhaps you educated someone with your comment. :)  You are clearly very smart.

Answer (score 5):

`1>/dev/null 2>&1`:
1 (stdout): /dev/null
2 (stderr): /dev/null

`2>&1 1>/dev/null`:
1 (stdout): /dev/null
2 (stderr): original destination of 1 (stdout)

---

The order is important because they are processed left-to-right, using the current values of the descriptors at that point.

Let's look at `1>/dev/null 2>&1` with two different starting conditions:

```
            Original           After 1>/dev/null  After 2>&1
            -----------------  -----------------  -----------------
1 (stdout): /dev/tty           /dev/null          /dev/null
2 (stderr): /dev/tty           /dev/tty           /dev/null
```

```
            Original           After 1>/dev/null  After 2>&1
            -----------------  -----------------  -----------------
1 (stdout): /tmp/stdout        /dev/null          /dev/null
2 (stderr): /tmp/stderr        /tmp/stderr        /dev/null
```

Now, let's look at `2>&1 1>/dev/null` with the same starting conditions.

```
            Original           After 2>&1         After 1>/dev/null
            -----------------  -----------------  -----------------
1 (stdout): /dev/tty           /dev/tty           /dev/null
2 (stderr): /dev/tty           /dev/tty           /dev/tty
```

```
            Original           After 2>&1         After 1>/dev/null
            -----------------  -----------------  -----------------
1 (stdout): /tmp/stdout        /tmp/stdout        /dev/null
2 (stderr): /tmp/stderr        /tmp/stdout        /tmp/stdout
```

---

Demo

`a`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
print STDOUT "Sent to STDOUT\n";
print STDERR "Sent to STDERR\n";
```

```
$ ( exec 1>/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr; ./a )

$ cat /tmp/stdout; echo .
Sent to STDOUT
.

$ cat /tmp/stderr; echo .
Sent to STDERR
.
```

```
$ ( exec 1>/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr; ./a 2>&1 1>/dev/null )

$ cat /tmp/stdout; echo .
Sent to STDERR
.

$ cat /tmp/stderr; echo .
.
```

```
$ ( exec 1>/tmp/stdout 2>/tmp/stderr; ./a 1>/dev/null 2>&1 )

$ cat /tmp/stdout; echo .
.

$ cat /tmp/stderr; echo .
.
```